# How to fix right click on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, touchpad

I have troubles with my right click on touchpad, it is working as macOS(you have to click left click with two fingers). But it doesnt work properly, so sometimes it works as double, and sometimes as ordinary. I want to set right click as RIGHT CLICK, not as double finger click on left click.

Regards

Comment: This is probably a better fit for https://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 2):

UPD: I found an answer. To make it u just need to write

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad click-method 'default'`

'finders' - for right click as double finger left click

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal and install tweaks

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

Once installed, press Super/Windows key to open the Application menu and search for ‘tweaks’. Click on Tweaks to start the program.

In the GNOME Tweaks, go to Keyboard & Mouse in the left sidebar and under Mouse Click Emulation section and select **Area**.

- for more details check [this](https://itsfoss.com/fix-right-click-touchpad-ubuntu/)